# MailMerge seem to open Excel file twice?

Tags: excel, ms-word

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.MainDocumentType = wdCatalog
.OpenDataSource Name:=excelfile, _
Connection:="Entire spreadsheet", SubType:=8, ReadOnly:=True
''# Range = Selection.Range
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.Execute
End With ''# Activedocument
DDETerminateAll
```

Why does this code open "excelfile" twice to excel, one of these is readonly.  How can I close these Excel files from Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbooks can be closed with this VBA code

`Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close`

You can add this to the end, so that no prompts to save are displayed if the file has been updated and not saved.

```
 SaveChanges:=False
```

Excel can be closed via VBA with if called from within Excel.

```
Application.Quit
```

If called from outside Excel, you will need to set a reference to Excel and then close it.

```
Set appExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
appExcel.Quit
```

You need to ensure that all Workbooks are closed or saved, otherwise Excel will prompt the user to save

Comment: thanks, but how to run workbooks.close or excel quit from Word macro??  Word opens the excel via DDE and leaves it open

Comment: With DDE, once the merge document is closed, Excel will automatically be closed as well.  The output of the merge does not need to be closed for this to occur.

Answer (score 0):

From VBA:

```
Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object
Dim objProcess As Object
Dim objList As Object
Dim errCode As Integer

Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 'Connect to CIMV2 Namespace

Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery _
("select * from win32_process where name='EXCEL.EXE'") 'Find the process to terminate

For Each objProcess In objList

    errCode = objProcess.Terminate 'Terminates a process and all of its threads.

Next
```

Would kill all instances of Excel.

Comment: I want to kill a chosen one, just DDE opened one, that has a specific xls file open, how to do that?